# when i edit my css file and refresh my page , changes does not apear

Tags: javascript, html, css, xampp

i'm using xampp for local server and running the apache and Mysql services , 
and move my php  and css file to "htdocs" folder , i write some codes in the php file and link css to php 
when i edit css file and then refresh the page i wrote , the changes i done doesn't appear .
i refresh the page several times but nothing will happen
but when i turn off the computer and back tomorrow , the changes will appear .

whats the problem ?
this is code i wrote in head tag

```
<head>
       <!-- Insert to your webpage before the </head> -->
    <script src="sliderengine/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="sliderengine/amazingslider.js"></script>

    <script src="sliderengine/initslider-1.js"></script>
    <!-- End of head section HTML codes -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css"> 
    <title>tak mobl</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Are your changes being cached? How are you refreshing the page and which browser are you using?

Comment: You old style is cached. For chrome, ctrl+shift+r for hard refresh. You want to check for other browsers too.

Comment: i use sublime text editor for wrote the codes ... at first save the file then open it wit h chrome and refresh the page with f5

Comment: hard refresh (ctrl + f5) - stylesheets are cached by the browser and you must force them to be re-downloaded if you want to see any changes

Comment: the methods you say i did but unfortunately nothing happened